# How to disable HMAC Authentication in C# Web API Rest Webservice

Tags: rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api, hmac

I am working on a C# Web API REST webservice that should be used for webhooks calls.

My problem is that when I try to connect to my webservice and call my controller, I always get an error message about ms-signature parameter. The only way to call my controller is to use HMAC authentication in the client side (ie SHA calculations on a secret key and the JSON data to be send to the webservice). It seems thata HMAC authentication is set by default, even if I don't want it.

I added a BasicAuthenticationFilter class for login and password check, and it works, but I still have the error message about ms-signature parameter before I can call my controller.

What should I do to disable HMAC authentication in my REST webservice? Basic Authentication by login and password is enough security for me.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer was that if I do not want SHA authentication, I need to use Nu-Get to install AspNet.Webhooks.Receiver.Generic package rather than AspNet.WebHooks.Receiver.Custom package. Some changes must be applied to the code, but I finally get ride of SHA authetification which seems to be set by default in Custom WebHooks receivers.